# JUnit equality test suddenly started failing on Jenkins, but not locally in Maven or Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, junit, jenkins, powermock

I have a very strange case where a single test that has been passing for several hundred builds has started failing, but only on the Jenkins site. It hasn't been modified since it's creation. Folders have recently been moved around, but I don't see how that would affect the test results, and no other tests have started failing.

The test is simply checking for equality of a returned object. It essentially looks like this:

```java
Trajectory[] trajectory = new Trajectory[Trajectories.numTrajectories];

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < Trajectories.numTrajectories; i++) {
        trajectory[i] = mock(Trajectory.class);

        // Mock the creation of trajectories
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Trajectory.class).withArguments(
                "filename" + i).thenReturn(trajectory[i]);
    }

    Trajectories.create();
}

@Test
public void testCreated() {
    // Verify that the created trajectories are correctly returned
    for (int i = 0; i < Trajectories.numTrajectories; i++) {
        assertEquals(trajectory[i], Trajectories.get(i));
    }
}
```

And `Trajectories.create()` looks like:

```java
public static void create() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numTrajectories; i++) {
        Trajectory t = new Trajectory("filename" + i);
        tList.add(t);
    }
}
```

So when the `Trajectory` object is created in `Trajectories.create()`, PowerMock injects a mock in its place. We then compare that this mock was correctly returned.

I even added some logging to compare the output from running locally vs on the Jenkins server with `System.out.println(trajectory[i] + "; " + Trajectories.get(i))`. Locally, everything matches up:

```
Mock for Trajectory, hashCode: 1327390425; Mock for Trajectory, hashCode: 1327390425
Mock for Trajectory, hashCode: 1189682735; Mock for Trajectory, hashCode: 1189682735
...
```

But on Jenkins, I get:

```
Running modelClasses.TestTrajectories
Mock for Trajectory, hashCode: 1455537357; Mock for Trajectory, hashCode: 1230136122
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.393 sec <<< FAILURE!
testCreated(modelClasses.TestTrajectories)  Time elapsed: 0.077 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<Mock for Trajectory, hashCode: 1455537357> but was:<Mock for Trajectory, hashCode: 1230136122>
```

And as we can see, the hashes are different. I don't understand what could possibly be different on this Jenkins server that would cause this difference.

The Jenkins server is running on a Linux distro. The Jenkins Cobertura, Maven, and Git plugins are used. The Maven goal used is `clean cobertura:cobertura -Dcobertura.report.format=xml`.

**Does anyone know what may be causing this inconsistency?**

EDIT: It's honestly not a very good test. It doesn't really test anything useful, and seems more like a test for PowerMock than this code, but I'm still very curious as to why it would suddenly start failing.

Comment: Does `Trajectory` have overrides for `equals` and `getHashCode`?

Comment: @metacubed No, it doesn't.

Comment: There are two tests in this test class (Tests run: 2), may be a side effect of the second one ?

Comment: Did you try to run locally `mvn clean cobertura:cobertura -Dcobertura.report.format=xml`

Comment: @gontard Yes. This particular test does succeed with that goal. I don't normally run that goal locally, though, because it gives me out of memory errors later on and I end up having to ^C to exit (these errors aren't seen when using `mvn clean test`, so I presume there's a bug in Cobertura).

Comment: Which version of cobertura do you use ?

Comment: It's not specified. Cobertura is not in the POM (since we only use it on Jenkins). I'm under the presumption that specifying the full command uses the latest version